# Change value into integer in js

Tags: javascript, php

Maybe You know how to help me. How to change something in javascript that when you select a combination of "pack" changed to integer values. Now how do I type a value, eg. 1.53 and change combinations, is it still in decimal  and I would like to get an integer value ( someting like round() in php).

[shop test page](http://anda2015.pro-linuxpl.com/index.php?id_product=2553&controller=product&search_query=933&results=1340#/jednostka-miaryqty-)

Comment: Try using Math.round()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Javascript `Math.round()` function. It is exactly what you need. It takes a decimal and returns an integer.

I've given some examples below:

```
var x;

// Returns the value 20
x = Math.round(20.49);

// Returns the value 21
x = Math.round(20.5);

// Returns the value -20
x = Math.round(-20.5);

// Returns the value -21
x = Math.round(-20.51);
```

For more information, see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

---

You can also use `Math.round10()` to specify number of decimal places or integer places you want to round off to like this:

```
Math.round10(55.55, -1);   // 55.6
Math.round10(55.549, -1);  // 55.5
Math.round10(55, 1);       // 60
Math.round10(54.9, 1);     // 50
Math.round10(-55.55, -1);  // -55.5
Math.round10(-55.551, -1); // -55.6
Math.round10(-55, 1);      // -50
Math.round10(-55.1, 1);    // -60
```

You can pass `-1` as the second parameter to round to the first decimal place, `-2` to round to the second decimal place, etc.

Similarly, you can pass `1` or `2` as the second parameter to `Math.round10` to round off to the 1st or 2nd integer place.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know maybe how to find a piece of code that is responsible for showing the value

Comment: After storing the value in a variable `x`, you can do `console.log(x)` (to print it in the console) or `alert(x)` (to display it in a pop-up window).

If you have a `<div>` with id "box" where you want to display it, use `document.getElementById("box").innerHTML=x;`